# How to set my NumericUpDown on Database

Tags: c#, numericupdown

For Example, My Item_Quantity on my Table is 50,
then my NumericUpDown's Minimum will be 1 and 50?
Im using C# and MySQL and I cant make it work.

**Edit:**

this is my code:

```
string MyConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Port=3307;database=invpos;Uid=root;Pwd=''";

    public void LoadGrid()
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
        connection.Open();

        try
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from items";
            MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adap.Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Clone();
            }
        }
    }

    public void ComboBox()
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
        connection.Open();        
        MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select Item_Name from items", connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adap.Fill(ds);
        comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Item_Name";
    }     
    private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadGrid();
        ComboBox();

    }
```

I hope that someone can help me :(

Comment: Post your code and more details of what you've tried or you probably won't get a response on here.

Comment: I'd expect a NumericUpDown to be on a UI... it's not really a database concept.

Comment: Where is `NumericUpDown` on your code?

Comment: I have put it on my gui but I dont know how to make it work on my Table "Items" so I havent made a code out of it :(

Comment: 1/ Get instance from GUI. (nudQuantity)
2/ Set minimum = 1: `nudQuantity.Minimum = 1;`
3/ Set maximum = 50 (get from your query) : `nudQuantity.Maximum = 50;`

Refer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: how can I get it from my database's quantity?
I know that the minimum will always be 1, but the maximum will be set on the Item_Quantity of my table, but that is the question, how can I get the value on my Item_Quantity?

Comment: It's mean you don't know how to get data from database or something wrong when you query to your database, right?
If so, please clarify your question!

Comment: This is what I want to happen:
Example:
Database: Item_Quantity = 50

and I want to set my NumericUpDown's Maximum Value into Item_Quantity's value :(

Comment: What is the name of `NumericUpDown`?

Comment: Name: numericUpDown1

Comment: I still need help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is what I want to happen: Example: Database: Item_Quantity = 50 and I want to set my NumericUpDown's Maximum Value into Item_Quantity's value :(

As I understand, you don't know how to get the maximum value of `NumericUpDown`?

Try this:

```
int itemQuantity = numericUpDown1.Maximum; //Get maximum value of `NumericUpDown`
int currentValue = numericUpdown1.Value; //Get current value of `NumericUpDown`
```

Does it solve your problem?

***Update**

```
try 
{
   MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
   cmd.CommandText = "Update <your table> set <column> = " + itemQuantity;
   //Use Command Parameter will be better.
   cmd.executeNonQuery(); //execute update.
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   //Catch exception
}
```

Comment: Im sorry if my english is kinda rusty, I know how to set it to maximum and value but I dont know how to set its maximum the same as the Item_Quantity on my database

Comment: Hmm, just update Item_Quantity on your database. Write a query and execute it. 
You have problem with execute query?

Comment: maybe you can give me an example code on how to do it?

Comment: @Jonathan: I've added code for update value on database. Please check it.

Comment: that's what I needed, thanks! :D

Comment: I can help you sooner if i get your question idea @@.